# Update info on a page without reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a simple feature:

- User enters their phone number
- I send a confirmation code via TwilioAPI
- They are redirected to a page where they write the code they've received

Sending is done by Sidekiq workers. I'm using the gem: https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status to check the status of a job.

```
job_id = MyJob.perform_async(*args)

Sidekiq::Status::queued?      job_id
Sidekiq::Status::working?     job_id
Sidekiq::Status::complete?    job_id
Sidekiq::Status::failed?      job_id
```

Those are some states the job is in. What I want to do is show what is happening to the end user on 'Enter code' page without them having to reload the page.

So, when I check

> Sidekiq::Status::complete? 123

and the job is complete, they would see a check mark and a word 'Sent'.

but if the status is

> Sidekiq::Status::failed? 123

then they would be notified to try again.

How to go about checking the status and displaying the results (progress) on the same page in real time?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- simple: have the job id returned to clientside javascript, make a status action that will return job status by its id and poll it every N seconds in javascript (but not too often, as this can produce unnecessary server load)
- more 'realtimish': set up some comet server like private_pub and have your job push its status to client at the very start, finish and on error